# Como cargar xaml at runtime pero desde otro proyecto con xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Tengo 2 proyectos xamarin forms:
 Uno se llama App29 y es el principal y otro se llama App1. Lo que quiero es hacer es que al presionar un botón yo pueda ir a una content page del proyecto App1. Es esto posible? Como se hace. Lo intente de esta forma pero me da error:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page pag = new App1.App().LoadFromXaml(typeof(App1.App)).MainPage;

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(pag);
        }
```

[image: rin]

Answer (score 0):

reemplazarlo con esta línea de código:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new App1());
```

esto es suficiente para llamar la siguiente página.